# Make layer from selected features in python add-in

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, python-addin

There is a problem in my arcgis add-in when I try to create layer from selected features of 'fc' layer, add-in button creates layer from all features of 'fc' layer not only selected features. When i try to do this process in arcmap python window, it works for both Make Feature layer management and copy features management. But in add-in it doesn't work for both analyses.

Here is my code:

```
class ButtonClass17(object):
"""Implementation for PPPpoint_addin.button_2 (Button)"""
fc = r"C:\New_Geodatabase.gdb\test"
def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    self.checked = False
def onClick(self):
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc,'kapi3')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be creating a feature layer from a `Layer` in the Table Of Contents, not from a geodatabase feature class.

1. [Get access to the layer and then get the selected features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm#M1_GUID-A1071A05-599A-4662-8354-4F676BA87878).
2. Use the `objectid`s you get in the step 1 to form the where clause for the `Make Feature Layer` tool.